# RPM; requirement only for installation

Tags: rpm, uninstallation

For my RPM-image, I want a requirement - for automatic installation - to another RPM that is needed, but not crucial; i.e. - I don't want the **un**install of the required RPM to trigger the uninstall of my RPM.

I understand that this is contradictive to the RPM-dependancy-system, but perhaps there are other ways to achieve this? NB; I'm not looking for the --nodeps flag.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `Recommends` option for **weak** dependencies:

```
Recommends: other-rpm
```

for reference: http://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html

> Weak: By default the dependency solver shall attempt to process the
>   dependency as though it were strong. If this is results in an error
>   then they should be ignored and not trigger an error or warning.

Comment: Hi Chris, that's probably what I want. Only downside for me is that I'm currently on a platform (rhel 7.4 / rpm 4.11) for which this feature is to new. Thanks nonetheless.